# Make a curve in a div with background image

Tags: html, image, css

I'm stuck with one task and I can't find any solution over the internet.
I have this situation:

[image]

Images 1 and 2 has background images.

I need one 1st or 2nd image have that bump. 
If it would be 1st image, that bump should extend div bottom and overlay the 2nd background.
If it would be 2nd div then I need like a crater/hole at the top and be under 1st div.

I can't cut my images to .png/.gif and cut with that bump in photoshop. These images are changed by client, so he can't prepare exact images all the time, so I need to extend them by code.

I tried to radial-gradient() background and cut with svg, but those aren't supported by Firefox.

Is it possible to make this with code who adapts to all background images?

Comment: If you can't do this using imagery then you could use clipping in SVG. Note however that this is unsupported in IE, Edge and Safari, although you don't really have much of an alternative given your requirements

Comment: Is the bottom image changed? Looks like a solid colour currently?

Comment: @timothyclifford, yes bottom div also can be with background image. I found solutions how to cut pieces like this in solid colours div's, but it nothing works when bg images are in divs.

Comment: What value has the `background-position` and `background-size`?

Comment: @LGSon it doesn't matter as long as they cover whole div. At the moment they are  `background-size: cover; background-position: center;`

Comment: It matter a lot, as to solve this using html only, you need to add a pseudo element to the div which holds the image, and then push that one down, and on top of that you need to assign the same image to the pseudo and position it so they fit and look as one ... I will think a little about this and how it can be done

Comment: @LGSon it's not necessary to solve this using html only, I can use js, jQuery etc. But I don't want to use some kind of strange library for this one element. I tried to play with pseudo elements, but it doesn't worked for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses background-size: cover, so it is easier to adapt. (It would be easier with known dimension images).

The drawback is a little complex markup, 3 auxiliar divs are needed.

The curves are standard border-radius, so that can be adjusted as needed

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  position: relative;
}
.up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}
.addon {
  width: 25%;
  height: calc(100% + 40px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 37.5%;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
}
.addon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -150%;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.down {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 40px;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
.addleft {
  width: 37.5%;
  height: calc(100% + 40px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: tomato;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: 0px 0px;
}
.addleft:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 266.667%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.addright {
  width: 37.5%;
  height: calc(100% + 40px);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: 0px 0px;
}
.addright:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 266.667%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="up">
    <div class="addon"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
    <div class="addleft"></div>
    <div class="addright"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use border-color

**border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;**

Basically you need to mark some percentage of left and right of the image border-color as transparent.

And then set **border-radius** to give the curve

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can show what do you have in mind? Because I can't understand how you make border appear just in the middle and then make that shape. I created fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yj7u7vLc/